# Oomph MacMapKit Drawing Wrong

Tags: cocoa, mapkit

I've integrated Oomph MacMapKit in one of my projects, I did all the steps. But there is a problem.
I'm using a NSToolbar and switching between the views. whenever I'm in my map page if I switch into another page and then switch back to the map page, the map is drew under the MKMapView and MKMapView is white but I can navigate in map by dragging mouse in the white area.

I've tried it in another project as well, And it acts just like this again.

Normal Look

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf4AL.png]

After switching back

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOJK6.png]

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

This code is running in my window controller delegate for switching pages

```
- (NSView*)viewForTag:(int)tag
{
    switch (tag)
    {
        case 0:
            return [firstViewController view];
            break;
        case 1:
            return [secondViewController view];
            break;
        default:
            return [firstViewController view];
            break;
    }
}

- (IBAction)switchViews:(id)sender
{
    NSView* currentView = [self viewForTag:[sender tag]];
    NSView* previousView = [self viewForTag:currentViewTag];

    currentViewTag = [sender tag];

    [[[[self window] contentView] animator] replaceSubview:previousView with:currentView];
}
```

There is no special code in maps page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I integrated Oomph MapKit as well in my app - including the switching of views - and found it working flawlessly. You'll need to post some code before you get any reasonable answers to this question.

Comment: Thanks Roger, But there is no special code in maps page, However I updated the question with code from main window for switching views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Map Kit is a bit buggy sometimes, changing my way of presenting views solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot fault your code. I presume you stepped through your code and checked that all views are properly added and removed. Also, you might want to check what frame is set for your map view after the switch. If the NSRect for the frame is where your white space is, somehow MKMapView is not keen on being added to and removed from the view stack.

It's a long shot, but you could try one of the following:

- Use `setHidden:` to temporarily make your map view invisible, in stead of removing and adding it. Not sure, but you might gain a bit of performance from this as well as hiding and showing is probably less expensive than adding and removing...
- Use `addSubView:` and `removeFromSuperview` to switch your views. This might need some code to provide for setting the framing of the views right or have a "default" frame handy that you can use when you add a view.

Bottom line MKMapView is wrapper around WebView, which sometimes seems to behave a bit odd.